# Change Events Calendar URL for specific category in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to change the URLs of the single event pages created by the Events Calendar WordPress plugin but only for a specific category. The default URL is `'http://www.example.com/events/post name'` and I want to change it to `'http://www.example.com/webinars/post name'` but only if the event has a category of webinar.

I created a function for changing the permalink:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'change_webinar_links', 10, 3 );
function change_webinar_links($permalink, $post) {
    if(get_post_type() == 'tribe_events' && has_category('webinar', $post->ID) ) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/webinars/' . $post->post_name  ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

I am stuck on creating a rewrite function. I couldn't find an example that applies to my situation.

UPDATE: I came up with some code which doesn't work but it at least shows what kind of syntax I'm looking for:

```
add_action( 'tribe_pre_rewrite', 'webinar_rewrite_rule' );
function webinar_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
    '^events/([^/]*)/?',
    'webinars/$matches[1]',
    'top'
    );
}
```

Could anyone help me with the rewrite rule?

Comment: What's the input and output that you expect from your regex?

Comment: I'm assuming the input would be '/events/' and the output would be '/webinars/'.

Comment: Just to confirm, do you want a regex to change all such urls `http://www.example.com/events/post name` to this: `http://www.example.com/webinars/post name`?

Comment: No just those who have a category of webinar.

Comment: Still not clear enough. If you could post an input and desired output for the regex, it would be better..

Comment: That is part of the reason why I'm asking the question because I not sure what to put in the regex. My end goal is to change the events url when it is in the webinar category from 'www.example.com/events/post_name' to 'www.example.com/webinars/post_name'. I'm not sure how else to explain it.